# Prove that $k^2+k+1$ is not divisible by $101$ for any natural $k.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that $k^2+k+1$ is not divisible by $101$ for any natural $k.$

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MSE. Please provide some context to your question such as what you've tried so far (and possibly are stuck on), where the question comes from, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\large \bmod 101\!:\,\ k^{\large\color{#0a0}3}\equiv 1\equiv k^{\large 100}\,\Rightarrow\, k^{\large\color{#c00}1}\equiv 1\ $ by $\ 100 = \color{#c00}1 + \color{#0a0}3(33)\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $101|k^{2}+k+1$, then $101|4(k^{2} + k + 1) = (2k+1)^{2} + 3$, which implies that $\left(\frac{-3}{101}\right) = 1$. However, you may show that $\left (\frac{-3}{101}\right) = -1$ by using the quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$k^2+k+1\equiv0(\mod101).$$
$k\equiv0(\mod101)$ is impossible, which says that we can assume that $k$ is not divisible by $101$.

Now, $$(k-1)(k^2+k+1)\equiv0(\mod101)$$ or
$$k^3\equiv1(\mod101).$$
But by the Fermat's Little theorem $$k^{100}\equiv1(\mod101),$$
which gives $$k\equiv1(\mod101),$$
which gives $1^2+1+1$ is divisible by $101$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: How did u make the transition from k^100= 1 mod 101 to k=1 mod 101?

Comment: @Joshua Haim Mamou because also $k^3\equiv1(\mod101),$ which gives $k^{100}= k\left(k^3\right)^{33}\equiv k.$